# Classifying captured images with camera

Tags: ibm-watson, visual-recognition

is anyone familiar with the steps or source code required to classify an image that was captured with an internal camera(android) using visual recognition service in java? Any suggestions that could lead me to a solution would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is an Android SDK to use the IBM Watson services- https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk

This blog will help you integrate Watson Visual Recognition with your Android app:
https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/visual-recognition-in-android-using-ibm-watson-9b1fea83e8d

This blog will help you to train Watson Visual Recognition service: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/developing-a-image-classifier-using-watson-visual-recognition-on-watson-studio/